# Google Analytics not recording custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics

In 2018, I created four custom dimensions for my GA property. They have been correctly collected and are available through the relevant GA reports.

Last week, I added an extra custom dimension, but this custom dimension is not being recorded. I fail to see why.

First, I added the custom dimension under "Custom Definitions" -> "Custom Dimensions", for the property in question.

[image]

Then, I map the name of the custom dimension to something more readable, in the header of each page that's recording pageviews through GA.

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', {
    'custom_map': {
        ...
        'dimension5': 'primaryCategory'
    }
});
```

Finally, I assign values to the custom dimensions.

```
gtag('event', 'add_dimensions', {
    ...
    'primaryCategory' : '<?php print $primaryCategory; ?>'
});
```

But, in no report is this new custom dimension available.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing your custom dimension value with an event tag it won't appear in Pageview report. 
In order to have it reported within page path, you may pass it withing the `config` command. You'll need to define your `custom_map` before with a set command:

```
gtag('set', {
  'custom_map': {
      ...
      'dimension5': 'primaryCategory'
    }
  });

gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', { 'primaryCategory' : '<?php print $primaryCategory; ?>' });
```

In that case, `dimension5` will be passed within `pageview` event and properly reported.

Here's a working [sample](http://ppchead.com/gtg.html) and you could see custom dimension value passed within Tag Assistant.

Also consider reviewing the scope of your custom dimension. While having it as `user` dimension you'll only be able to report the last value within the user session.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now seeing 'primaryCategory' in my reports. I have changed the 'scope' of my custom dimension to 'Hit', but that does not appear to have changed the reporting on the last value set, only. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) updated scope processing will not have 'backfill' effect so your old data will stay the same 2) updated scope processing might took some time,

Comment: to have all the things clean and tidy i'd suggest you to adding all the new dimension to avoid collisions

Comment: It appears you're right. It seems to have taken some time for the changes to properly affect the recording of data. However, interestingly, it also seems that the data related to the differently defined 'dimension5' has disappeared. Either way, this is totally fine for me :)