# Google Analytics Custom dimension is undefined in gtag

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

I have set up 4 dimensions. My code as follows,

```
 <script>//<![CDATA[
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-1');

        gtag('set', {
            'user_id': _spPageInfo.userId,
            'JobTitle': jobTitle,
            'Department': department,
            'UserLocation': Location
        });
        gtag('send', 'pageview');

        //]]>
    </script>
    <script>//<![CDATA[
        // <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push({
                'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
                event: 'gtm.js'
            });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s),
                dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.src =
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXX');

        // <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

        //]]>
    </script>
```

I have set up dimenstion in tag manager as well.
In debug mode i can see "Conatiner Loaded" instead of "Page Load",

[image: <p]

And  in datalayer i can not see any event name or dimension name.

[image]

After 24 hours also its showing undefined.
Please,Can anyone guide me what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to pass `custom_map` parameter with your `config` command you map your named dimension values to custom dimension. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935092/google-analytics-not-recording-custom-dimension/59947237#59947237). Moreover, you'll need to call `set` before `config` since `config` is actually passing pageview hit to google analytics so calling set after config won't affect your data
Eventually, your code would look something like this:

```
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('set', {'custom_map': {
  'dimension1': 'department',
  'dimension2': 'jobTitile',
  // the same for other custom dimensions
}})
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-1', { 'jobTitile': 'engineer', 'department':'maintenance' });
```

Moreover, avoid using both GTM and `gtag` code at the same time otherwise you'll get duplicated data sent to analytics.

Comment: Thanks now i am seeing `Container Loaded:
1
{event: 'gtm.js', gtm.start: 1591683140892, gtm.uniqueEventId: 4}` and on document load or Dom load Window Loaded:

{event: 'gtm.load', gtm.uniqueEventId: 215}
Data Layer values after this Message:
`{
 event: 'gtm.load',
gtm: {start: 1591683669174, uniqueEventId: 215},
custom_map: {
dimension1: 'user_id',
dimension2: 'JobTitle',
dimension3: 'Department',
dimension4: 'FacilityLocation'
}
}`
Variable values are still undefined.

Comment: what you're seeing in GTM will be undefined because GTM uses another mechanism for analytics custom dimensions. If you're about using GTM please refer to respective GTM docs https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164990?hl=en

Comment: Does it mean that i need to remove manually entered custom dimension from GTM and i have to keep only in JS code?
Because i am seeing now against my id number under job title two row, one with "JobTitle" and another with "Developer". "JobTitle" is my dimension name.

Comment: keep all the `gtag` calls in the code if you're going to use `gtag` analytics implementation.
remove all the code if you're going to use GTM and would like to see the data in preview tab. Follow the GTM instructions to configure the analytics tag properly.

Comment: once again -- GTM and GTM preview mode has nothing to do with your `gtag` code. You won't see any confirmation from GTM preview tab even if your `gtag` code is working properly. GTM and `gtag` are two distinct incompatible tools.

Comment: Thank you very much. You clear my concepts very well.